# has something changed with decorating a component with reduxForm?

Tags: redux, redux-form

here is the code to tie reduxForm with my view layer.. and i keep on getting a syntax error! Can someone shed a light?

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (80:43)
78 | const fields = ['title', 'platform']
79 | 
80 | const BannerFormContainer = reduxForm({form: 'banner', fields})(BannerNewForm);
                               error right here ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reduxForm` wrapper is the same as it has been for a good while now. However on line `78` you're declaring a const `fields` in what seems to be object format, but you're not inside of an object. Perhaps replace the `:` with a `=`.

`const fields = ['title', 'platform'];`

Comment: hey thanks for leaving a comment. so i did find that i was not assigning it correctly soon after i posted..but that was not the reason why it gave that syntax error.

Comment: I made some dumb mistake on the view layer; i forgot to close the tag..

Answer (score 0):

try `const fields = ['title', 'platform'];`

replace   **:**    by  **=**

**syntax error with defining variable**